# How to make the multiple meteor project connect to one mongodb server ?

Tags: mongodb, ethereum

I have 2 meteor project.
The first is ethereum mist, and the second is ethereum wallet(meteor-dapp-wallet).

Also I have mongodb.

Then I have to connect the 2 meteor project to use the 1 mongodb.

How?

Comment: thank you for you support @Veeram. and answer please.

Comment: I'm not a pro at meteor .. but I'm certain that if you specify same `MONGO_URL` to both project ... bother project will run smoothly ...

Comment: both * ... not bother ... :| ... stackoverflow doesn't allow me to edit comment anymore :(